# Disable a script when another script is active

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I have got two scene change scripts, both which are attached to two different game objects. But for some reason, one script affects both game objects. So I am trying to temporarily disable one of the scripts when the other script is active on the other game object. Here is what I have but this is returning the error, "BasketballSceneChange' is a type, which is not valid in the given context".

```
    **GameObject.Find("pPrism1").GetComponent(BasketballSceneChange).enabled = false;**
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name == "MWalk")
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("BWalk");

    }


    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) && SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name == "BWalk")
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("Basketball");

    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) && SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name == "Football")
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("SWalk");

    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) && SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name == "SWalk")
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("MWalk");

    }
}
```

}

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: It's either `GetComponent(typeof(BasketballSceneChange))` or `GetComponent<BasketballSceneChange>()` - it's clearly highlighted in the examples in the documentation: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

`GameObject.Find("pPrism1").GetComponent(BasketballSceneChange).enabled = false;`

to

```
 var myVariable = GetComponent(BasketballSceneChange) as myBaseClass;

 myVariable.enabled = false;
```

change **myBaseClass** to class which shows your Scene.

Comment: No, `GetComponent(BasketballSceneChange)` will not compile

Comment: @UnholySheep check my edit in my response you must write .GetComponent<BasketballSceneChange>().enabled

Answer (score 1):

You could avoid using GetComponent just declaring a public variable and assigning it from the inspector.

```
public AnotherScript theOtherScript;
void Update()
{
   if(theOtherScript != null && theOtherScript.enabled)
   {
      theOtherScript.enabled = false;
   }
}
```

Check this [Tutorial](https://unity3d.com/es/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/enabling-and-disabling-components)

Other way is Finding the gameobject and geting the component as you did.

I've read your code again and I found the error that doesn't compile the line:

```
GameObject.Find("pPrism1").GetComponent(BasketballSceneChange).enabled = false;
```

should be

```
GameObject.Find("pPrism1").GetComponent<BasketballSceneChange>().enabled = false;
```